# Getting a weird Exception when I build my Project

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, designer

When i build my project I'm getting a weird exception message.
There are no Build Errors and when i click to Reload the designer the Windows renders correctly but its causing Visual Studio to crash from time to time and im more curious as to whats causing it.

I have recently added in a custom control that I have build but I don't know if that the reason for this exception.

[image: ScreenShot of Exception]

When I comment out the custom control and rebuild I'm still seeing this Exception, if anyone can add light into where to look or how to fix it, i have tried on here to make scene of the exception message but i couldn't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface is your project referencing?

Comment: There appears to be no Reference to it in my project, I tried adding a reference but it made no difference. Is there anywhere else i can check except my references folder?